# Increase length of vertical bar

Tags: latex

How can I increase the length of vertical bar in the following?

```
\[M=\frac{e^{4}}{2k_1}\Big{\{}-(1+t)\left|_{-1}^0\right.+(1-2t)\left|_{0}^1 \right. \Big{\}}\]
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try `\bigg|`:

```
\left(1-2t\right)\bigg|^{0}_{-1}
```

[image]

(Although the official recommended method is `\left. \right\vert`)